3ds2 Mastercard android SDK. Failed to validate 'acsURL'
I am trying to implement 3ds2 Mastercard android sdk with kotlin and ReactNative. I am following documentation came along with SDK, still i am getting Failed to validate 'acsURL'. While doing some tinkering i have found acs url that i am receiving in response is not a complete URL. i am just getting the location.
Now, am i doing something wrong here? 
I am creating a session and updating it through API call as document suggested.
Then initialising the SDK, and then authenticating 3ds\
In logs, i can see Signature verified! but it is an error log for some reason.
SDK initialisation
     lifecycleScope.launch {
        try {
            GatewaySDK.initialize(
                applicationContext as Application,
                merchantId,
                merchantName,
                merchantUrl,
                region,
            )
            promise.resolve(null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.message?.let { Log.e(TAG, it) }
        }
    }

authentication
AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(
            this,
            session,
            authTransactionId,
        ){ response ->
            when (response.recommendation) {
                AuthenticationRecommendation.PROCEED -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "AUTHENTICATION RESPONSE:  $response")
                }
                AuthenticationRecommendation.DO_NOT_PROCEED -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "AUTHENTICATION RESPONSE DO NOT PROCEED:  $response.error")
                }
                null -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "AUTHENTICATION ERROR:  $response")
                }
            }
        }




Error Log
2024-09-10 01:12:56.883 12541-12541 MSJWE                   com.sdkdemo                          E  Signature verified!


2024-09-10 01:03:10.054 12541-12541 TransactionImpl         com.sdkdemo                          E  AcsSignedContent#verifyAndBuild failed
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to validate 'acsURL'!
                                                                                                        at com.usdk.android.a.a(Unknown Source:71)
                                                                                                        at com.usdk.android.a.a(Unknown Source:97)
                                                                                                        at com.usdk.android.TransactionImpl.a(Unknown Source:84)
                                                                                                        at com.usdk.android.TransactionImpl.doChallenge(Unknown Source:17)
                                                                                                        at com.mastercard.gateway.android.sdk.AuthenticationHandler$suspendDoChallenge$2.invokeSuspend(Authentication.kt:400)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    


